# Clojure - launch 'for i in range(0, x)' (begin ques)

Tags: functional-programming, clojure

all I want to do is increment 'i' as list elements go, but it seems that sequence starts from '1' as incrementing go first (?)

```
(fn [lst]
(doseq [i (for [i (range (count lst))] (inc i))]
        (println i)

))
```

All I want to get is '0' for 1-range list, but it returns '1'. I tried to 'for [i 0 (range (count lst))', but it errors. Ty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `doseq` if you want to perform side effects only - without collecting the result.
Use `for` loop if you want to collect the result.

Somehow you weirdly use both, `doseq` an `for`.

I think, what you want is this:

```
(defn count-list [lst]
  (doseq [i (range (count lst))]
    (println i)))
```

In Python, there is `enumerate()` to loop over lists
and at the same time to have an index (position of the element in the list).

```
l = ['a', 'b', 'c']
for i, el in enumerate(l):
   print(f"index: {i} value: {el}")
```

In Clojure you could do this with map-indexed:

```
(def l ["a" "b" "c"])

(map-indexed (fn [i el] [i el]) l)
;; => ([0 "a"] [1 "b"] [2 "c"])
```

Just I want to say is: In Python, looping over a list
using its index is quite C-ish - and not Pythonic.
Also in Clojure, you rarely need the index.
Because you could do:

```
(def l ["a" "b" "c"])

(for [el l]
  ; do something with `el` here
  ; and return the value which should be collected!
  el)
```

similar to Python's list-comprehensions:

```
[el for el in l]
```